# Aligning two set of data of different lengths

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, alignment

I've never posted on here before and I'm an amatuer when it comes to using Excel and Google Sheets so if this problem has a very simple solution thats why I've not seen it. And yes I also know Excel is probably the better choice for trying to solve this problem, if it can be done in sheets it's easier for me but if not then it will have to be done in excel.

Long story short, I work in an RDC for a supermarket and I have a very long list of stores with a product ID (PIN) they've ordered and an associated demand for that PIN. But it comes from head office in 2 different "tags". I need to be able to compare both lists, only list 1 has stores that list 2 doesn't, and list 2 has stores that list 1 doesn't. Which means side by side they are ofset and don't line up for an easy comparison.

I should add that the whole list is about 80 stores long and has about 64,000 rows of data. I've shared a sheet publicly of just 3 products if anyone would like to play around with it then feel free to. I've also manually gone through the first 3 products and lined them up and highlighted the stores that don't have a record in both lists of data. I've only done that for a visualisation, at the end of the day I'm only interested in the data that's in both lists. Anything highlighted in red (Bold on here) or any blank spaces can be deleted.

```
Store 1 PIN 1   Total Demand 1      Store 2 Pin 2   Total Demand 2
1   100274252   8       1   100274252   10
12  100274252   33      12  100274252   10
140 100274252   19      140 100274252   10
205 100274252   39      205 100274252   10
276 100274252   5       276 100274252   10
278 100274252   10      278 100274252   10
284 100274252   6       284 100274252   10
290 100274252   8       290 100274252   10
293 100274252   8       293 100274252   10
294 100274252   7       294 100274252   10
295 100274252   8       295 100274252   10
296 100274252   32      296 100274252   10
298 100274252   8       298 100274252   10
299 100274252   20      299 100274252   10
302 100274252   81      302 100274252   30
305 100274252   18      305 100274252   10
307 100274252   112     306 100274252   10
309 100274252   112     307 100274252   10
313 100274252   18      309 100274252   30
314 100274252   6       313 100274252   10
316 100274252   31      314 100274252   10
345 100274252   10      315 100274252   30
353 100274252   8       316 100274252   10
355 100274252   8       345 100274252   10

Store 1 PIN 1   Total Demand 1      Store 2 PIN 2   Total Demand 2
1   100274252   8       1   100274252   10
12  100274252   33      12  100274252   10
140 100274252   19      140 100274252   10
205 100274252   39      205 100274252   10
276 100274252   5       276 100274252   10
278 100274252   10      278 100274252   10
284 100274252   6       284 100274252   10
290 100274252   8       290 100274252   10
293 100274252   8       293 100274252   10
294 100274252   7       294 100274252   10
295 100274252   8       295 100274252   10
296 100274252   32      296 100274252   10
298 100274252   8       298 100274252   10
299 100274252   20      299 100274252   10
302 100274252   81      302 100274252   30
305 100274252   18      305 100274252   10
                      **306 100274252   10**
307 100274252   112     307 100274252   10
309 100274252   112     309 100274252   30
313 100274252   18      313 100274252   10
314 100274252   6       314 100274252   10
                      **315 100274252   30**
316 100274252   31      316 100274252   10
345 100274252   10      345 100274252   10
```

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIEk2.png)
[Aligning the data manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNDym.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQ_69oSTm92tak9Zqpekbkkb2gLxLi1kmaoJj3lAE-s/edit?usp=sharing

I have no idea where to start with this, but I need to find a way of writing a script or formula that can be repeated for the whole 64,000 rows of data. I could probably ask someone in IT but get this feeling I'll learn more on here and will get a quicker response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

I created a new tab called "Filtered Data".

I created the Following Headers in 'Filtered Data'!A1:D1:

[image: Screenshot1]

In  'Filtered Data'!A2, I used the following formula:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER('Raw Data'!$A$2:$B,MATCH('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A&'Raw Data'!$B$2:$B,'Raw Data'!$E$2:$E&'Raw Data'!$F$2:$F,0)))

In 'Filtered Data'!C2, I used the following formula:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B,'Raw Data'!$A$2:$A&'Raw Data'!$B$2:$B,'Raw Data'!$C$2:$C))

This pulls the matching values from 'Raw Data'!C2:C.

In 'Filtered Data'!D2, I used the following formula:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP($A$2:$A&$B$2:$B,'Raw Data'!E2:E&'Raw Data'!F2:F,'Raw Data'!G2:G))

This pulls the matching values from 'Raw Data'!G2:G.

Here is a screenshot of the results:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I looked over the data to see if there were any discrepancies and I did not find any.  See if this might work for your use case.

Comment: So I added a tab on there for all the data and applied your formula's to it in the same way, modifying the sheet name and the ranges. It does work, but then stops working after a couple of products.I added a column called "Does Match" with a simple IF AND formula to check if the two lists match, and it stops matching on row 55.

Comment: I think this might be because the entry for Store 486 PIN 101705755, is on row 56 on the 1st set of data and row 68 on the 2nd set of data. Which is a bigger gap than any previous entry

Comment: Will modify my answer to reflect another solution.

Comment: Modified.  You might try this.